# How do I get TypeScript to distinguish "namespace" from "static attributes"?

Tags: typescript

TypeScript doesn't seem to do a very good job of separating namespace from static properties.

```js
class ClassA {
  static ClassB = class {
  };
}

type T = ClassA // ok

type T = ClassA.ClassB // error: 'ClassA' only refers to a type, but is being used as a namespace here.

new ClassA.ClassB() // ok
```

In the above example I want the code to not report errors.

Comment: `Foo.Type` is a variable exists in runtime space. It does not exist in type space.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What specific type do you want `T` to be?  Maybe you want it to be `(typeof Foo)["Type"]` to be the type of the `Type` constructor?  Or maybe you want it to be `InstanceType<(typeof Foo)["Type"]>` to be the type of a `Type` instance?  Or something else? Given that there is no type named `Foo.Type`, and you haven't shown how you want to use `T`, we just have to guess.  Please [edit] to clarify what you want `T` to resolve to (preferably with example usages) and then we can answer.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To circumvent the syntax of namespace in typescript, the following scheme is used instead:

```
class ClassA {
  static ClassB = class {
  };
}


type T = InstanceType<typeof ClassA.ClassB> // ok

// or
type T = typeof ClassA.ClassB.prototype // ok


new ClassA.ClassB() // ok
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your class to be a `namespace`, merge it with a `namespace`

```
class Foo {}
namespace Foo {
   export class Type {}
}

type T = Foo.Type // ok
new Foo.Type() // ok
```

Classes (unlike namespaces) can't have static types on them